# How do I establish a connection to MySQL via VB & display simple query results on a form?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a project in Visual Studio 2008 and there is a working data connection to a MySQL database.  In other words, I can query the db directly from Visual Studio and it will display the results.

I've tried a couple of approaches that I found online for writing a connection string and accessing the db, but no luck yet.

All I'm trying to do is code a button to query the db and then reset the text property of a label/textbox to display the results based upon another label/textbox value.

The pseudo-code I am imagining is something like this:

```
    Private Sub query_submit_button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles query_submit_button.Click
        result_textbox.Text = SELECT field FROM table WHERE otherfield = key_textbox.Text
    End Sub
```

I didn't see any related questions posted on SO - forgive me if I missed one that already exists and this is a dupe.

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

---

EDIT
Using MySQL 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the [ODBC Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=6CCD8427-1017-4F33-A062-D165078E32B1&displaylang=en) and then reference, import, and use it to query the database through a [ODBCCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.aspx) instance.

```
'Put this at the very top of your .VB file...
Imports System.Data.ODBC

'Put this in some method in your code when you are ready to query the DB...
Using connection As New OdbcConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New OdbcCommand(strSqlQuery, connection)
    connection.Open()
    result_textbox.Text = command.ExecuteScalar.ToString
End Using
```

Comment: do i need to download that provider?  i mean i already have an established, working (query-able) connection.  also, im guessing i have to declare the query string - `Dim strSqlQuery As String` and `strSqlQuery = "select ..."` ?

Comment: ok this all looks fine and dandy to me and my compiler, BUT what is the `connectionString` ?  it looks like thats all ill need to wax this out

Comment: that second link you have is good, thanks - im looking on there for the example connection string but cant find it yet - if you know what it should be, post it and i can test

Comment: its just for access dbs - you know how to modify it to conform to mysql?

Comment: connectionString was a string variable with your connection string.  See http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql for examples of mySql connection strings.

Answer (score 0):

i used DaMartyr's answer to get 99% there, but needed to add this declaration:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=SERVER;uid=USERID;pwd=PASSWORD;database=DATABASE"
```

just replace the `SERVER`, `USERID`, `PASSWORD`, & `DATABASE` with your personal settings